# Why low data throughput is observed when iperf tried with UDP packet size set below 2000?

Tags: sockets, udp, bandwidth, lte, iperf

I'm experimenting on an LTE connection for checking the maximum rate of bandwidth can be achieved in the uplink.While creating iperf sessions i observed that i'm not able to go beyond 100Kbps in the uplink when the UDP packet size is set as 1400.Apparently when i increased the packet size to 50000 i was able to achieve 2 Mbps in the same link.

Can someone guide me why this performance difference is observed ?When i tried this in a wired channel there i was able to achieve 10Mbps with UDP packet size set as 1400 itself.

What could be the reason for this?

Will trying TCP/IP instead of UDP increase the data throughput?

Comment: I guess RF protocols use temporal domain multiplexing. When there are several clients on a base station, you get a lot of time wasted waiting for the temporal slot between successive packets when there are many idle clients. With large MTU you seem to be able to skew bandwidth sharing in your favor.

Answer (score 0):

It probably matters where fragmentation is done - application or IP stack. Your observations show you that IP stack is more efficient.

TCP will be slower. TCP's built-in congestion control will not allow you to send packets until some of already sent have been ACK-ed. That adds round-trip time to performance considerations.

UDP has no such restrictions. It can (ab)use the network to its full potential.